# Calculates b/w two row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

Can any one Help me Please I want to Calculate 2 or more row Record see Below Query.

```
SELECT docs_DocCode, SUM(invd_Qty) AS Total_IN
FROM   dbo.SI_InventoryDetail

WHERE  (docs_DocCode = 'D.C') AND (itm_ItemCode = '0101050000083') OR
       (docs_DocCode = 'STO') AND (itm_ItemCode = '0101050000083') OR
       (docs_DocCode = 'SAO') AND (itm_ItemCode = '0101050000083') OR
       (docs_DocCode = 'IOB') AND (itm_ItemCode = '0101050000083') OR
       (docs_DocCode = 'GRN') AND (itm_ItemCode = '0101050000083') OR
       (docs_DocCode = 'STI') AND (itm_ItemCode = '0101050000083') OR
       (docs_DocCode = 'SAI') AND (itm_ItemCode = '0101050000083') OR
       (docs_DocCode = 'SRN') AND (itm_ItemCode = '0101050000083') OR
       (docs_DocCode = 'PRN') AND (itm_ItemCode = '0101050000083')
GROUP BY docs_DocCode
```

ABove Query Give me Result as below

```
dics_doccode   Total
D.C            328.00000000
GRN            205.00000000
IOB             96.00000000
SAI             66.00000000
SAO             51.00000000
SRN             14.00000000
STI            150.00000000
STO            150.00000000
```

Now i want To ADD (D.C+STI+SAI) - (GRN+STI+SAI+IOB) = One Value

And i am using SQL SERVER 2000

Thankx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE
             WHEN docs_DocCode IN ('D.C', 'STI', 'SAI') THEN invd_Qty
             WHEN docs_DocCode IN ('GRN', 'STI', 'SAI', 'IOB') THEN -1 * invd_Qty
             ELSE 0
           END) AS One_Value
....
```

Note that `invd_Qty` that do not belong to any from `'D.C', 'STI', 'SAI', 'GRN', 'STI', 'SAI', 'IOB'` will not be added.

PS: (D.C+**STI+SAI**) - (**GRN+STI**+SAI+IOB) - I've emphasized the pointless (??) parts. It is equal to `D.C. - (SAI + IOB)`

Comment: Dear THankx for Quick Reply but you given Query is not working

Comment: My I want to Add Where Cluse here w hich Identify my ITEM Basicaly that Calculation is For Current Stock Status....

Comment: @Brave ali Khatri: `is not working` is not enough detailed description of an issue. And I cannot get your complete 2nd comment :-S

Comment: I think i have mention Complete Senario what i wanted to do

Comment: @Brave ali Khatri Please can you tell, if your comment is longer and we see it somewhat truncated here. I asked at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72195/sometimes-i-do-not-see-a-complete-comment-at-stack-overflow-only if this can happen and they say, that you typed the 3 dots

Comment: @bernd_k: he typed even **4** dots in the end ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved My problem thankx to  **"Zerkms"** Below is My Query and It Result

SELECT Itm_itemcode,

```
    SUM(CASE WHEN docs_DocCode IN ('D.C', 'STO', 'SAO','PRN') THEN INVD_QTY END ) - 
    SUM(CASE WHEN docs_DocCode IN ('GRN', 'STI', 'SAI','SRN','IOB') THEN invd_Qty END) AS Qty
```

From SI_InventoryDetail

Where Itm_itemcode = '0101050000083'

group by Itm_itemcode

**Result**

Item_code           Qty
0101050000083   -2.00000000

Thankx
Brave ali khatri

Comment: if you found my answer useful you can check it with green mark below the vote number :3